# Summation expression in R with spin()

Tags: r, knitr

In my R code, I have:

```
#' $\sum(r^2,i=1,t))$
```

I assumed it would spin() and then output the proper expression() output.

What it is giving me is ∑(r2,i=1,t))

How do I format this code such that i=1 is the subscript on the operator and t is the superscript?

Answer (score 1):

Equations are included using the LaTeX notation:

```
$\sum_i^t(r^2)$
```

Useful guide: https://wch.github.io/latexsheet/

Comment: `$\sum_{i=1}^t(r^2)$` to explicitly have `i=1` as subscript.